# Sequelize update millions of records using offset missing some rows to update

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using sequalize modal to update. while updating bulky some rows are missing updates. here is my code. table have more the 60L records and need to update all.

```
runBatch(offset){
 let limit = 100000;
 db.sequelize.models.transactions.schema("queenDB").findAll({
     limit: limit,
     offset: offset,
     order: [
         ['txndate', 'asc']
     ]
 }).then(async(tranzObj)=> {
 for (let tranz of tranzObj) {
   /* some calculations */
   await tranz.update({ quantity: number, dateupdated: new Date() });
 }
 
 if (tranzObj.length === limit) {
        runBatch(offset + limit)
    } else {
        console.log("batch success")
 }
 })
}
```

while run this some rows were updated as null in DB, but I verified the quantity before update no rows have a null quantity.

any recommended way or how to resolve this? in node.js

Comment: At least you should turn your code into async and use `await` and also you don't wait for results of each update and that way your transaction completed almost immediately and will drop all unfinished updates.

Comment: I tried with async and await but the same result.

Comment: Please update the post with the latest code with `async/await`

Comment: please look into the new code, updated with async/await

Comment: I still see you use `then` and don't wait for `runBatch` inside `if (tranzObj.length === limit)`